# Why is there no declension for the comparative adjective "weniger"?

Tags: declension

> Dadurch verbraucht dieses Auto **weniger** Sprit!
>
> {instead of}: Dadurch verbraucht dieses Auto weniger**en** Sprit! [with Starke Flexion]

I suppose this *weniger* is not an adverb, but an adjective qualifying the following noun *Sprit*. I was surprised to find out that the comparative declension for *wenig*  apparently does not exist to begin with. I wonder why?

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/wenig:A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some adjectives like **wenig**, **etwas**, **mehr**,  **manch**, **solch**, **viel**, **welch** are called as *Adjektive mit Nullartikeldeklination*. There is a beneficial [tutorial](http://mein-deutschbuch.de/adjektivdeklination-nach-nullartikel.html) if you want to learn more about these types of adjectives.

Examples from this tutorial;

> Adjektive mit Nullartikeldeklination nach folgenden Begleitern stark
> dekliniert:
>
> Eure Kinder sollten **mehr** frisches Obst essen.
>
> Mit **etwas** gutem Willen lassen sich sicherlich all deine Probleme lösen.
>
> Der Ozean verbirgt **manch** kostbare Perle.
>
> **Solch** dummes Zeug habe ich schon lange nicht mehr gehört.
>
> Hinter der Grenze zu Polen kann man **viel** billigere Schuhe kaufen als bei uns.
>
> **Welch** große Nase hat dieser Mann.
>
> Auf der Versammlung wurden nur **wenig** neue Fakten genannt.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't read your linked canoo article properly. It classifies *wenig* as  **[Adjektive, unflektiert und attributiv](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-A/Texte/Attrib-Pred.html)**. So, this adjective (not everyone would agree it is one, [Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/wenig) insists it is an adverb) is **not** flexed. This is also true for its comparative and superlative.